# How to use TeeChart to draw the 3D surface chart (VC++6.0)

Tags: 3d, teechart

I used the code: m_chart.Series(0).GetAsSurface().AddXYZ(30,40,50,NULL,10); 
But running error：Invalid class typecast.

Can you take me a sample code ? (The best use of C++)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a Series? In the code above, you accessing to the first series in the chart (index 0) and you are casting it to a SurcafeSeries. So the first series in the chart must be a Surface to run that line of code.

I'd also suggest you reading [this post](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?p=19750#p19750) to understand what's the correct way to populate these kind of series. It's a VCL thread but the same applies to TeeChart ActiveX.

Comment: Thanks! But still did not solve my problem. TeeChart less good information. ^_^

Comment: Try setting a blank string "" instead of NULL in the fourth parameter. Without a detailed explanation including a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it's difficult to find the correct guesses.

Comment: Still a runtime error : Invalid class typecast. -_- 
(The compiler can be passed)  Thank you all the same!